# Restore permission denied on Ubuntu for files/folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I've recently uploaded a cakephp web app on apache2 on a  Linux server on an amazon ec2 instance. In order to edit files for development, i use filezilla to open files, make changes locally and then upload them. But to go around permissions to read write, I use:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/myFolder/ -R
```

Only problem is, once I'm done editing, I don't know how to revert back to restricting permissions to avoid security issues. 
I now need to make virtual hosts so to add conf file in etc/apache2 I need to make it writeable. How to make the folder unwriteable again?

Answer (score 1):

Give these two a whack:

```
sudo find /var/www/yourfolder -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
sudo find /var/www/yourfolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

The first one sets the correct permissions for directories recursively, and the second one the correct permissions for the files. It's pretty well the standard permission set for apache servers.

Edit: for apache2.conf if you applied permissions recursively and need to change back - replace /var/www/ in the commands above with /etc/apache2/